# VB.net detect Mouse click outside form

Tags: vb.net, events

I want my application/windows form to be minimized when the user clicks outside the application window. How am I able to detect such an event?

Comment: Have you tried using the member Control.GotFocus Event ?

Comment: How about the Form's lost lost focus event?